# How to make a linq lambda expression and set the table to be used in the expression dynamically?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, lambda

I wanted to make the table used for the expression be set dynamically

Here is my code

```
PayoutEntities payoutdb = new PayoutEntities();

 public String AutoID(String idFormat, String tablename)
 {
    string curdate = DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString().Replace("/", "");

    if (tablename == "users"){
       var count = payoutdb.users.Count(x => x.userid.Substring(0,10) == idFormat + curdate);
   }else if (tablename == "transactions"){
       var count = payoutdb.transactions.Count(x => x.transid.Substring(0,10) == idFormat + curdate);
   }
      count++;
      string ID = idFormat + curdate + count.ToString("0000");
      return ID;
}
```

Currently I have an autoid function for all tables in my database so now I'm thinking of a way to make a shorter code rather than placing my code in an if statement. Is there anyway to set the table used in linq lambda expression dynamically?

Comment: The dynamic part is not only the table, but also the PK property. Where do you get `tablename` from when calling this method? Can you show the usage (calling code) of this method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My advice would be not to use a string to identify the table to use, but to make a generic function where the type of the table is the parameter of the generic function.

Assuming payoutDb is your DbContext, you can use [DbContext.Set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbcontext.set?view=entity-framework-6.2.0#System_Data_Entity_DbContext_Set__1) to access the proper table:

```
public string AutoId<TableType>(string idFormat)
{
    string curdate = DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString().Replace("/", "");
    var count = payoutdb.Set<TableType>()
                .Count(x => x.userid.Substring(0,10) == idFormat + curdate);
    count++;
    string ID = idFormat + curdate + count.ToString("0000");
    return ID;
}
```

note: every `x` in the Count is of type `TableType`, so it is a `user`, or a `transaction`.

Usage: Using your proposed code, somewhere in your code, you would call the function like this:

```
string someIdFormat = ...
string autoId = AutoId(someIdFormat, "users");
```

Using my proposed function this would become:

```
string autoId = AutoId<User>(someIdFormat);
```

One of the problems you'll have to overcome, is that you have to tell your AutoId function that `users` and `transactions` and all other tables you wanted to use in `AutoId` have a property `AutoId`.

A method you could use, would be to define an interface:

```
interface IAutoId
{
     string AutoId {get;}
}

class User : IAutoId
{
     public string AutoId {set; set;}
     ...
}
class Transation: IAutoId
 {
     public string AutoId {set; set;}
     ...
}

public string AutoId<TableType>(string idFormat) where TableType: IAutoId
{
    ...
```

If you don't want to do this for the tables that you want to use, consider telling the AutoId function which property it should use:

```
public string AutoId<TableType>(string idFormat, Func<TableType, string> propertySelector)
{
    ...
    var count = payoutdb.Set<TableType>()
                .Count(x => propertySelector(x).Substring(0,10) == idFormat + curdate);
    ...
}
```

You want the part `propertySelector(x)` to call `x.UserId`, so you would call the function like this:

```
string autoId = AutoId<User>(someIdFormat, user => user.UserId);
```

The nice thing about this method is that you can use your function also for other properties:

```
string autoId = AutoId<User>(someIdFormat, user => user.UserName);
```

Comment: Thanks for this @Harald Coppoolse :)

Answer (score 0):

The table is a property of PayoutEntities, so you could get that property by name using GetProperty(). Once you have the property, you should be able to use linq with it.

Comment: can you give me an example on how should i do that?

Comment: I'm sorry for asking again i'm just a beginner on linq but can you demonstrate it to me how will I apply it on my scenario?